# Jest - do something before every test

Tags: jestjs

Jest provides some useful methods for executing something before your tests: `beforeEach()` and `beforeAll()`. [Jest docs on setup](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/setup-teardown.html)

The issue with these is they can only be placed inside of a `describe` block. So if I have many files, each with their own describe block, I need to place to `beforeEach()` in every file.

How can I run some code before & after every test, while only adding it once (instead of adding it in every describe block)?

Comment: Maybe use an external file and import it, then call the function that does what you need in each case?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `globalSetup` Jest config key. It is an optional key and it can be used to run an async function once before all test suites.

Please see https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#globalsetup-string

Example of setting up `globalSetup` in `package.json`:

```
  jest: {
    globalSetup: "./path-to-global-setup.js"
  }
```

... or in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: "./path-to-global-setup.js"
};
```

Example of `global-setup.js` file:

```
module.exports = async function() {
  // do something
};
```

This file will **not be** transformed by `babel` when you run your test suite.